# Android: No output from Hugo DebugLog

Tags: android, hugo-logging

I am trying to use Hugo in my android project but am not seeing anything after putting `DebugLog` annotations in my project. I've tried putting them in Activities, Fragments and normal Java classes.

All of the above classes are in main app module, not library module.

Gradle changes:

top level gradle file:

```
dependencies {
 classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
```

app level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
```

`ANDROID_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION=3.0.1` if it's required.

Have been trying to get this work for some time now but no luck.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing dependency for processing annotations:

`api "com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-annotations:1.2.1"`

Also, try setting debug output level to `verbose` instead of `debug` in LogCat.

Comment: Do you really have your Hugo dependency defined like above? Then remove the ` characters so it looks like this:

classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'

Comment: Maybe you're missing additional dependency? See edited answer.